# Jackson Object mapper to convert java map to json maintaining order of keys

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using `jackson.map.ObjectMapper` API to convert map to json string. I am using writeValueAsString method to achieve this.

I pass a map sorted on the basis of values to `writeValueAsString` method. The JSON string which I get is resorted on the basis of keys.

Is there a way to convert maps to JSON string using jackson without disturbing the order of items in the map.

I tried setting `Feature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY` to false, but as per documentation it is applicable only for POJO types.

Any idea to implement the said behavior.

Comment: A generic map doesn't guarantee order of keys, so I don't see how you could do this.

Comment: You need to make sure you're using a map that maintains insertion order, that is a TreeMap as opposed to a HashMap.

Comment: I have used Treemmap only and the values are sorted the way I want. However, as soon as I pass my treemap (infact a object containing everal tree maps] to Jackson API to get JSON string, all my map values are resorted based on keys.

Comment: Please correct me If I am wrong, but I am not aware of any way to correctly create a Map sorted by values that is fully compatible with java SortedMap interface specification. A SortedSet of pairs would be ok. But Map will be wrong. Just updating the value on such map can brake everything. The Comparator<Key> that compares values is also braking a few rules! Please consider using SortedSet of Pairs.

Answer (score 17):

with Jackson 2.3.1 (don't know for previous versions) you can serialize a SortedMap, for example a TreeMap, the order will be respected.

Here is an exempale in junit 4:

```
    @Test
public void testSerialize() throws JsonProcessingException{
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES,false);
    om.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT,true);
    om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

    SortedMap<String,String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("aaa","AAA");

    map.put("bbb","BBB");
    map.put("ccc","CCC");
    map.put("ddd","DDD");

    sortedMap.putAll(map);

    System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(map));

    System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(sortedMap));


}
```

and here is the result:`

with a Map

```
{
  "aaa" : "AAA",
  "ddd" : "DDD",
  "ccc" : "CCC",
  "bbb" : "BBB"
}
```

with a SortedMap

```
{
  "aaa" : "AAA",
  "bbb" : "BBB",
  "ccc" : "CCC",
  "ddd" : "DDD"
}
```

`

The 1st serialization with a Map will not be ordered, 
The second one with a TreeMap will be ordered alphabeticaly using keys. you can pass a Comparator to the treeMap for a different order.

Edit: It also work on Jackson with a LinkedHashMap() even if this is not a SortedMap.  This is an implementation of Map that keep the order which keys were inserted into the map. This could be what your are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for giving time to this. I have tried with both treemap and linkedhashmap. And I am configuring my mapper to not sort the maps by using the below configuration property.          SORTED_MAPPER.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, false);
This works absolutely fine when I pass a map (treemap or linked hashmap) to writeValueAsString method as below SORTED_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(map);

Comment: However, I have 10 different maps to be converted to JSON and hence I cannot pass the map object to this method. Hence, I put all the maps in a object and pass this object to the method as SORTED_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(myObject) where myObject contains all the maps; Jackson API for some reason is not able to configure the maps in this case and resort all the maps based on keys.

Comment: Jackson is a bit problematic in certain edge cases and it is often best to implement your own serializer. (http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization).

Comment: @MartinKersten A custom Jackson-serialiser specific for Map, yes. For an instant I was afraid you were proposing to do all the JSON serialisation without any librairies. Do you have more information on that edge-case, Does it concern the map serialisation?

Comment: There are several cases the teams I supported finally went for custom serializers or when I am in command implement our own JSON serialization mechanism. JSON is fairly simple and supporting it directly is implemented easily. I am not a fan of annotations and hidden magic. Serialization concerns data directly and data is the main ingredients in our daily programming soup. So I like a data object being able to serialize itself rather than 'discover' how to serialize it. Whenever you have (schema) evolution things become messy. So custom almost always works best. Teams usually see it as relieve.